# How not to insert specific value into database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have MS SQL Server database and insert some values to one of the tables.

Let's say that the table contains columns `ID`, `int Status` and `text Text`.

If possible, I would like to create a trigger which prevents from writing specific incorrect status (say `1`) to the table. Instead, `0` should be written. However, other columns should be preserved when inserting new values:

If the new row written is (`1, 4, "some text"`), it is written as is.
If the new row written is (`1, 1, "another text"`), it is written as (`1, 0, "another text"`)

Is it possible to create such trigger? How?

**EDIT:** I need to allow writing such record even if status column is invalid, so foreign keys will not work for me.

Comment: Most definitely. An Insert trigger can do that. However for various reasons mostly related to ease of debugging and maintainability, i would suggest that you handle it in code instead of using triggers for this kind of logic. Also, if the status is a user input, wont you need to alert / warn the user if the status entered is incorrect instead of just changing it unknown to the user?

Comment: I am using ORM to write to a database and there are some situations when it inserts intermediate values with intermediate status. This is not too bad, however, if program crashes for some reasons, invalid status is stored in the database. So I cannot handle this in the code (this is third-party binary) and this is not user input.

Comment: Use transactions to ensure ACID if at all possible...

Comment: Thanks, but this is third-party ORM, I cannot. I need this hack to workaround third-party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need a foreign key to ensure data integrity even if you choose to use a trigger (though I would myself prefer a 'helper' stored proc -- triggers can cause debugging hell) e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE MyStuff 
(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 Status INTEGER NOT NULL 
    CHECK (Status IN (0, 1)), 
 UNIQUE (Status, ID) 
);

CREATE TABLE MyZeroStuff 
(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 Status INTEGER NOT NULL 
    CHECK (Status = 0), 
 FOREIGN KEY (Status, ID)
    REFERENCES MyStuff (Status, ID), 
 my_text VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER tr__MyZeroStuff
ON MyZeroStuff
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN; 
INSERT INTO MyZeroStuff (ID, Status, my_text)
SELECT i.ID, 0, i.my_text
  FROM inserted AS i;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

An insert trigger has been mentioned, but another way to achieve this is to have a foriegn key on your Status column which points back to a Status table - this will not allow the write and change the value, instead it will simply disallow the write if the foriegn key is not valid.

Check out [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) for more info on this option.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the subtle thing is that due to the task specific I need to allow writing such record even if status column is invalid so foreign keys will not work for me.